# Spark Cluster configuration

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using a spark cluster with of two nodes each having two executors(each using 2 cores and 6GB memory).

Is this a good cluster configuration for a faster execution of my spark jobs?

I am kind of new to spark and I am running a job on 80 million rows of data which includes shuffling heavy tasks like aggregate(count) and join operations(self join on a dataframe).

Bottlenecks:

1. Showing Insufficient resources for my executors while reading the data.
2. On a smaller dataset, it's taking a lot of time.

What should be my approach and how can I do away with my bottlenecks?
Any suggestion would be highly appreciable.

query= "(Select x,y,z from table) as df"

```
    jdbcDF = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", mysqlUrl) \
    .option("dbtable", query) \
    .option("user", mysqldetails[2]) \
    .option("password", mysqldetails[3]) \ 
    .option("numPartitions", "1000")\
    .load()
```

This gives me a dataframe which on jdbcDF.rdd.getNumPartitions() gives me value of 1. Am I missing something here?. I think I am not parallelizing my dataset.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to improve the performance of your application. PFB some of the points which may help.

1. Try to reduce the number of records and columns for processing. As you have mentioned you are new to spark and you might not need all 80 million rows, so you can filter the rows to whatever you require. Also, select the columns which is required but not all.
2. If you are using some data frequently then try considering caching the data, so that for the next operation it will be read from the memory.
3. If you are joining two DataFrames and if one of them is small enough to fit in memory then you can consider [broadcast join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.broadcast).
4. Increasing the resources might not improve the performance of your application in all cases, but looking at your configuration of the cluster, it should help. It might be good idea to throw some more resources and check the performance.
5. You can also try using Spark UI to monitor your application and see if there are few task which are taking long time than others. Then probably you need to deal with skewness of your data.
6. You can try considering to Partition your data based on the columns which you are using in your filter criteria.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations. I have already tried few of the points mentioned - I am only reading the required data and using the broadcast hash join. However I do not know much about accessing the spark UI to monitor my tasks and I figured that spark jdbc reader is not parallelizing my dataset when reading. It gives me data on a single partition regardless of the numPartitions mentioned in the configuration.

Comment: I have added a snippet of my code where seems to be an issue. Could you help me with this?

Comment: Once you created jdbcDF try repartitioning the DF based on some column and then check the partitions on new DF.

newdf = jdbcDF.repartition(1000, "col1")
newdf.rdd.getNumPartitions()

Comment: I am avoiding repartitioning because it involves reshuffling. Also it is not increasing my computational efficiency. I am confused why there is no partitioning while reading the data from db.